# click on the button to run php code and echo result

Tags: php, button, echo

I want to implement this script: http://www.daniloaz.com/en/560/programming/backup-de-bases-de-datos-mysql-con-php/

on my website to backup all the database at the end of the day.

May I know is it possible for me to put a button to click and run the script and echo the status after it finish without refreshing the page or bring me to a new page.

as at the moment i everyday need to go to the link: www.example.com/backup.php to do daily backup, I want this to ease my job :)

any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

what type of button? if html yes it's easy

have a button on what ever page you want along with a div like so:

```
<input type="button" name="perform_backup"  onclick="do_backup()"><div id="results"> No backup has been performed yet</>
```

then have a javascript which calls your backup php script like this

```
<script>  
 function do_backup(){
   var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var request = "http://www.example.com/backup.php " // this will prepare a request to your server
   xhReq.open("GET", request, false);  // send a request
   xhReq.send(null);
   document.getElementsByID("results").innerHTML=xhReq.responseText  /// this will display results

   }
</script>
```

then I would modify the script on your server to give more then a boolean variable but that's up to you. But whatever you choose it will be seen inside `<div id="results">` , without loading a new page... This method is called AJAX for future questions

Comment: but if already perform will it the result show "done" or "error" if the backup unsuccessfull?

Comment: it will show true or false , as that's what the php code return so false will show 0 in php and true something else ... though if you modify that code you can make it show whatever you want

Comment: sorry, im totally don't know ajax, but i use all the code provide by you, the button was nothing and when i click it nothing run. by the way i did change www.example.com to my web address but not working

Comment: Have you tested the  php script  not using my code? If it works...  Try typing in the url address in a Web browser and eye what happens

Comment: Btw...  This solution will have serious security problems,  I assume you know this / have address them somehow